# Asynctask with Progressdialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I'm using an Asynctask to execute a time-consuming method, `doStuff()`, which among other things allocates global data structures.  A debugger confirms that `doStuff()` is called, but when a new view is drawn at the end of the Asynctask, I get a null pointer exception while accessing the global data structures.  Here is the code:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected ProgressDialog dialog;

    public MyTask (Context context) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() { 
       super.onPreExecute();
       dialog.setMessage("Foo");
       dialog.show();    
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        doStuff();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I execute the Asynctask from multiple activities using `new MyTask(this).execute();`.

Comment: How are you determining the end of the `AsyncTask` to draw the new view?  It is not in your `onPostExecute`

Comment: After `new MyTask(this).execute();` I start an intent to go to the new view.

Comment: That sounds like your problem, `execute` starts the task, but you do not know that it is done until `onPostExecute` gets executed.  You either move your code to, or have a callback to it in `onPostExecute`

Comment: whatever you want to do after you are sure the asynctask is complete.  The code that is currently failing with the NPE, because it is likely that it is getting run and accessing things before they are fully initialized.

Comment: Okay, so Asynctasks are like threads, in that the main thread keeps on going as soon as the Asynctask starts, not when it finishes.  Thanks!  Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Exactly!  Posted answer below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AsyncTask` is a really a convenience wrapper around a background thread and a handler.  You are executing code before the background task finishes.  To know when the background task is finished, you need to put the code you want to execute or otherwise signal your main activity in `onPostExecute` (which will run on the UI/main thread) that the task is complete.  For more details, see the using AsyncTask section of the [Processes and Threads guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

Answer (score 0):

You must declare the ProgressDialog  in the Activity that you are using your AsyncTask

Comment: Why can't I share it between activities?  After all, I'm passing it the context of the calling activity.

Comment: See [this](http://rorraja.blogspot.ca/2012/03/show-progress-dialog-inside-asynctask.html) example.

Comment: I not sure... but I had problems with my ProgressDialog and AsyncTask and I solved in this way.